# Sharing Image to currently running app

Tags: android, image, keyboard

I have a keyboard with Images, i am sharing that image to another app via intent share. But, i want to share that particular image to my currently opened app.

Is it possible to disable Intent chooser and to send image directly to current running app ?

How ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Read more about intents: [Adroid References](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

So, to use intent without the choser, you can put the domain of an app that you want to open using this `Intent intent = new Intent("<Package name of the app>")`.

To know the Package name of an app running inside the emulator device, you can use the [DDMS](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/ddms.html). The package name of the apps running is like: `com.damain.name.somename`, look in the devices list.

Comment: I am sending to another app bro.. not in the same app. Using Virtual Image Keyboard

Comment: So, you can send by URI with the Intent, if you know the URI of the another app.

Comment: ya know, Done. But, How to get package name of currently running app inside InputMethodService ? I have issue with typecasting ActivityManager class. as java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.ActivityManager$RecentTaskInfo cannot be cast to android.app.ActivityManager$RunningAppProcessInfo

Comment: The Package name is from another app that you are not the owner ? If Yes, you need to install the app in a emulator or a rooted phone, and find the package name from the /data and search the package name of the app.

Comment: How can i do this ?

Comment: use the `adb shell` or the `Android Monitor`. More instructions: https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/ddms.html

Comment: Is it that you want?

Comment: yo, get package name from EditorInfo.

Comment: Hey, one more little issue, Image share with WhatsApp goes with Black background since i am using Transperent png images. i want that it go with white background. Any idea ?

Comment: I have just created the special images with white background and by checking package name, if its com.whatsapp then sending such images else default images will be sent.